# Images within Div's shift all to one side?

Tags: html

I have a top bar with text links and images; all the images are shifting to one side?[image]

The images should align next to their respective text links, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

here is the website:
http://www.heatx.org/productcart/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was looking at the URL you posted in Chrom DEV tools, and i found an entry in `pcHeaderFooter11.css`

```
#pcIconBar a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
}
```

Changed that to :

```
#pcIconBar a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

and voila! 
[image]

And please remember, elements with `display: block` tend to behave like `div` tags and end up in a separate space for themselves. is you want alignment like this, you're supposed to specify explicitly that you want the element to be `inline`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think i see a div in there called "pcIconBarRight" and left.
But personally i would create one div for every button/icon pair.

otherwise you can make the main div "relative" in your css and then move the child objects around based on that. (relative to the parent div (in this case pcIconBarRight)